# Custom Unmarshal with string split in Golang

Tags: json, string, go, unmarshalling

I have the following JSON

`{"student_number":1234567, "name":"John Doe", "subjects":"Chemistry-Maths-History-Geography"}`

I would like to unmarshal it in a struct, where one item (the subjects) are split on '-' into a `[]string`.

```
type Student struct {
  StudentNumber int       `json:"student_number"`
  Name          string    `json:"name"`
  Subjects []string 
}
```

I have attempted several different ways of achieving this with custom Unmarshalling using `strings.Split()`, but have not succeeded so far.

Is there any way to achieve this in the unmarshalling process? Or will I need to simply unmarshal as is and make the conversion afterward?

Comment: Of course you _can_ write your own UnmarshalJSON method to do this. But why bother? Plain and straight unmarshaling into a string and splitting afterwords is so much simpler, easier to test and less error prone.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easiest would be to define your own string slice type and implement [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) on that:

```
type strslice []string

func (ss *strslice) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    var s string
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &s); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    *ss = strings.Split(s, "-")
    return nil
}
```

And use this in your struct:

```
type Student struct {
    StudentNumber int      `json:"student_number"`
    Name          string   `json:"name"`
    Subjects      strslice `json:"subjects"`
}
```

And then it'll work:

```
func main() {
    var s Student
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(src), &s)
    fmt.Println(s, err)
}

const src = `{"student_number":1234567, "name":"John Doe", "subjects":"Chemistry-Maths-History-Geography"}`
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/FObyfS87AaL)):

```
{1234567 John Doe [Chemistry Maths History Geography]} <nil>
```

Comment: Works like a sunshine. Thanks! Would you agree with Volker's comment that doing it post-unmarshalling is actually a better solution?

Comment: @MarcoW Depends on your use case. If you only need the slice once, you may leave the field as a `string` in the struct, and add a method to the struct that splits it (or just split the field's value where needed). If you need it multiple times, the splitted parts may be stored (e.g. in an additional field), but at that point this solution is simpler.